# find dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let A
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1\\
-2 & -4 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
. Let D = $\{B\in\mathbb{R}^{3x3}| BA = \begin{pmatrix}0 &0&0\\0 &0&0\\0 &0&0\\\end{pmatrix}\}$. Find the dimension and basis.

i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: What is the basis of $\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3$ ?

Comment: Dimension and basis of what?

Comment: this is one element of the basis $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$. for he rest I will vary the position of 1

Comment: dim and basis of D

Comment: Starting with a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ would not work. There is no guarantee that there exists a subset for a basis for a vector space which forms a basis for a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we note that $BA = 0$ if and only if $Ba_j = 0$ for $j = 1, 2, 3$. But since $-5a_1 + 2a_2 = a_3$, $B \in D$ if and only if $Ba_j = 0$ for $j = 1,2$ if and only if
\begin{align}
b_{i1} - 2b_{i2} & = 0\\
2b_{i1} - 4b_{i2} + b_{i3} & = 0\\
\end{align}
for $i = 1,2,3$ if and only if
\begin{align}
b_{i1} & = 2b_{i2}\\
b_{i3} & = 0\\
\end{align}
for $i = 1,2,3$ if and only if
$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 2\alpha & \alpha & 0\\ 2\beta & \beta & 0 \\ 2\gamma & \gamma & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore $D$ has a spanning set
$$\{\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\}$$
It is easy to show this spanning set is linearly independent and therefore a basis for $D$.

Comment: i could not follow your notation. . Specifically, how did u get $b_{i3}=0$

Comment: $a_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$. $b_{ij}$ is the entry on the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column. $b_{i3} = 0$ since $b_{i3} = -2(b_{i1} - 2b_{i2})$ and we use the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

$BA = 0$ means every row of $B$ is in the left null space of $A.$ that is the same as belonging to right null space of $A^\top.$ rref gives $$A^\top = \pmatrix{1&-2&0\\2&-4&1\\-1&2&2}\to \pmatrix{1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$$
this has one free variable $y.$ set $y = 1.$ we get $z = 0, x - 2y = 0\to x = 2$

a basis for matrices $B$ is $\left\{ \pmatrix{2&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0&0&\\2&1&0\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0&0&\\0&0&0\\2&1&0}\right\}$

Comment: i followed until the (x,y,z)=(2,1,0). How did you find basis for B?

Comment: @user3382078, each row is a multiple of the row vector $(2,1,0)$ it is because we showed that $null(A^\top = span\{(2,1,0)\}$  that is $(2,1,0)A = (0,0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

What does $BA=0$ mean? It means that $\operatorname{Im} A \subseteq \operatorname{ker} B$. So we need to find the dimension of the image of $A$, or the rank of $A$ as this is the main restriction on our space. Then  we see that $B$ is really a map from $\mathbb{R}^3/\operatorname{Im} A$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and any such map gives such a $B$.

Since $\det A=0$, the rank of $A$ is not 3, but since it's clearly greater than 1 (since the rows are not all multiples of each other), the rank of $A$ is 2. Then these $B$ correspond to maps from the one dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3/\operatorname{Im} A$ since ($\dim\mathbb{R}^3/\operatorname{Im} A = \dim \mathbb{R}^3 -\dim \operatorname{Im} A = 3-2=1$) to $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is a space of dimension $3$. Thus the dimension of the space of such $B$ is 3.

To find a basis we note that since $A$ has rank $2$, there is a linear combination of the rows that gives 0, this can be found by solving the linear equation given by $\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix} A$.
Let $\alpha$ be the row vector corresponding to this solution.
Then a basis is given by $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \alpha \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \alpha \end{pmatrix}$.

Such an $\alpha$ is $(2,1,0)$ as in SRX's answer.